# A potentially dangerous Request &#8237

Tags: asp.net

Why does this on a query string trigger the validation request `%26%238237` which is `&#8237` Url Encoded?

`A potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value was detected from the client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to violation of built in security rules in the ASP. It was added to help prevent script-injection attacks

You could do one of the following:

1) Override the request validator to allow those characters

2) Disable the request validation in web.config

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
```

3) Set the requestValidationMode to 2.0 in your web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```